# XMLELEMENT doesnot display any data in the output window of Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to create an XML using the XMLELEMENT function of Oracle and while testing the query its working fine but as soon as I have added the XMLELEMENT function, its not displaying any data. Here is what I'm doing:

Normal Query:

```
SELECT NAME from sysadm.USER where ID = '121';
**Output** - Sahil
```

XML Query:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
nametag xmltype;
BEGIN
  SELECT XMLELEMENT("USERNAME", NAME) into nametag from sysadm.USER where ID = '121';
END;

**Output** - anonymous block completed
```

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You haven't only added `xmlelement`, you've wrapped that in an anonymous PL/SQL block - do you actually have a reason to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually display the value of your variable, which you could do with:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
nametag xmltype;
BEGIN
  SELECT XMLELEMENT("USERNAME", NAME) into nametag from sysadm.USER where ID = '121';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nametag.getstringval());
END;
```

at least as long as the generated string is less than 32k. But using `dbms_output` should be avoided except for debugging really, as you don't generally have control over whether someone else calling your code has server output enabled.

You could also use bind variables, e.g.:

```
VAR result CLOB;

DECLARE 
nametag xmltype;
BEGIN
  SELECT XMLELEMENT("USERNAME", NAME) into nametag from sysadm.USER where ID = '121';
  :result := nametag.getclobval();
END;
/

print result
```

You don't need to use a PL/SQL block at all though - you can just do:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("USERNAME", NAME) from sysadm.USER where ID = '121';
```

optionally adding a `.getclobval()` or `.getstringval()` to change the output. You may, depending on the length of the generated XML, need to `set long` to a higher value to display it all in the worksheet. If you run as a statement rather than a script the query result output grid will just show `(XMLTYPE)`, but you can double-click on that to see the value, or right-click and choose 'single record view', to see the actual content.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the details answer. This is what i'm looking at. Just wanted to know why Oracle doesn't behave like SQL Server and display the result into the output window. Many thanks anyway :)

Comment: Because it isn't SQL Server *8-) [12c added something slightly similar though](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/release_changes.htm#LNPLS118).